# PHP session isn't set

Tags: php, session

I have php upload images code and i try set variables session if my file will be uploaded next redirect user to index.php and show him jquery dialog

Upload checking code

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$new_name)) {
            $_SESSION['udalo'];
          header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

index.php isset

```
if( isset($_SESSION['udalo']))
        {
            echo '<script> dodano(); </script>';
        }
```

yes, I have entered session_start in 2 files

Answer (score 3):

you never create the variable `$_SESSION['udalo']`

at least give it a value even if not used:

`$_SESSION['udalo']='yes';` or something you cant just drop a variable name and expect magic